# Does adding a reference to std::queue create a copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have a bunch of unrelated structs which I'd like to add to a std::queue. I'm using a struct named `message` which I use to encapsulate the unrelated structs in order to store them in the same queue.

```
struct message {
    char *struct_pointer;
    size_t struct_size;
};

struct confirmer {
    int32_t hello;
    int32_t yellow;
    double jello;
}
```

Inside a message, I then call

```
confirmer *confirm = new confirmer();
confirmer->hello = 100;
confirmer->yellow = 000;
confirmer->jello = 123.324;

message my_message = {(char *)confirm, sizeof(struct confirmer)};       
other_namespace::do_things_to_message(my_message);
```

where `do_things_to_message` takes in a reference to a `struct message`.

My question is that inside the function `do_things_to_message`, if I add the parameter `curr_message` (which is a reference) to a `std::container`, will it create a copy of the reference and store that in the container? I.e.

```
void do_things_to_message(struct message& curr_message) {
    my_queue.push(curr_message) //where my_queue is a std::queue my_queue<message>
    //do other things...
    }
```

So what is my_queue actually storing? A copy of the object? The original object? Something else?

Comment: You don't need all that code to ask this question. A simple `struct Foo {};` would have done.

Comment: The declaration of `my_queue` tells you what it stores.

Comment: @melpomene so a copy? I'm sorry its not very clear to me

Comment: it stores a copy (unless you `std::move` the argument into the call). In your case, be very careful of memory leaks.

Comment: @RichardHodges thanks. As for memory leaks, `my_message` would get destroyed once it goes out of scope (since its a local variable), but I'd have to call `delete` on `curr_message.struct_pointer` once I pop it out of the queue, right? Not missing anything else, right?

Comment: @user2635088 I am concerned that you have cast an object pointer to a char* and are then going to call delete on the char* pointer - this is UB. disaster awaits you. What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: You're not encapsulating structs; you're pointing to them. This is C++, so why don't you use inheritance and virtual dispatch, like everyone else?

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm popping the queue on another thread and passing the struct data to `send` via sockets. Would casting it back as a `confirmer` pointer and then freeing it be valid?

Comment: @user2635088 that would be better. You're still in trouble though because of structure packing and byte ordering. It would be better if your message objects were polymorphic objects that knew how to serialise and deserialise themselves over the wire. Either that or store the serialised representation in the queue (for example as a `vector<char>`).

Comment: @RichardHodges gotcha thanks. My struct is pragma pack(1) and it'll be going from a little endian machine to another little endian machine 100% of the time so hopefully I have the byte ordering and structure packing covered.

Comment: @user2635088 `#pragma pack(1)` is a terrible idea!  Please serialize things properly - it really makes life much simpler in the long run.